# Nice way to map with potential failure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to parse a series of `Json` objects with potential failures that cancel the whole function.

Ideally, I'd do something like:

```
fn .... -> Result<Vec<Video>, YoutubeParseError> {
    ...
    let videos = try!(doc.find("items").
        and_then(Json::as_array).
        ok_or(YoutubeParseError));

    Ok(videos.into_iter().
        map(|item| try!(json_to_video(item))).
        collect())
}
```

But of course try doesn't escape the `map()` on error and instead of `Result<Vec<Video>,_>`, I get `Vec<Result<Video,_>>`. I could rewrite this as manual iteration adding elements into a new vec, but I feel like I'm missing some simpler way of handling this.

Is there some existing function that would get me from `Iter<Result<T>>` to `Result<Vec<T>,_>` easily?

Comment: I don't think that second try! works as you want. try! will get you out of the closure. By the way have you looked at `flat_map`

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming languages you can treat options and results as containers and Rust is similar, so you can `map` / `flat_map` over them. You could do this with `flat_map`. If `videos` is already a vector, you can just test for expected number of `Ok`'s against a `flat_map`ped length to decide whether to return `Ok`.

However, you should try to keep things lazy and not continue parsing after the first failure. `take_while` would be an option here. Either way, you will need to track if you saw a `parse_failure` along the way. Something like below works - it demonstrates how `flat_map` drops `Error`s, but it parses more than necessary.  You could also use a `.filter` and then `.map` to get the parse result

```
fn get_videos(test: &Vec<&str>) -> Result<Vec<u32>, &'static str> {
    let videos = ...
    let expected = videos.len();
    let extracted = v.into_iter().flat_map(|x| json_to_video(x)).collect();
    if extracted.len() == expected {
        Ok(extracted)
    } else {
        Err("not_ok")
    }
}
```

Here's an option to do it lazily -

```
let extracted = videos.map(|x|json_to_video(x))
                      .take_while(|x|x.is_ok())
                      .map(|x|x.ok().unwrap())
                      .collect()
```

You can call `unwrap` as you dropped everything starting at first failure. Now you return `Ok` if `extracted.len() == videos.len()`

Comment: @shepmaster ...as written it parses beyond the first fail.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point! I'll clear out my comment to prevent any confusion.